# Why are Facebook Graph API stories published, but there are no impressions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I have been using the standard Graph API sharing option (POSTing to /me/feed) to post content on behalf of my app's users. I posted several hundred stories. According to my app's Insights stats, there are hundreds of "Stories Publishes". That makes sense. However, there are 0 "Story Impressions" and 0 "Story Clicks". How is that possible?

There should be at least a few impressions based on me just testing if this worked on several accounts. I can see that the posts are showing up on the profile.

What happens to the published stories?

Here is screenshot to illustrate my situation:
[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm currently having the same issue with **Open Graph stories**

Comment: I was not able to solve this problem, but this was 3 years ago with an old version of API.